# We want to connect PowerBI to mysql database hosted on an external server

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

The database is available externally via hostname, username and password but limited to IP. Currently, Power BI cannot see our database as I have not whitelisted the PowerBI IP address on the external database. How do I find out the Power BI IP address, so that we can whitelist this on the external database and allow PowerBI to view the data? Remote connections have been enabled?

Answer (score 2):

PowerBI is Azure cloud-based service and its IP address changes with time within each region.
You can download the [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) to configure your firewall rules.

Also refer:

1. [Community forum link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/What-is-the-right-method-to-allow-Power-BI-service-IPs-through/td-p/977691)
2. [Documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-whitelist-urls)
3. [Service gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem#ports)